# Segments in circles - 2 column proofs - video issue

Tags: geometry

I've been revising some geometry theorems, watching YouTube videos made by @The Organic Chemistry Tutor. I found 2 issues, which I'm not sure about.

[in first video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PT7WpRj8ro&index=112&list=PL0o_zxa4K1BVkRxCZubMPcCJ5Q5QwZdEM)
The proof starts at 5:40. In step 4, in the column proof (at 6:54) he says that segment BD is perpendicular to segment AC. I don't understand how come, assuming all we know are the givens in the example, bisector BD doesn't have to be perpendicular, or am I wrong?

[in second video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GppOSNTi5OA&index=111&list=PL0o_zxa4K1BVkRxCZubMPcCJ5Q5QwZdEM)
It starts at 2:50. He says "You need to know that if 2 chords od a circle are equidistant from the centre, then they are congruent". and then "Because segment EF is congruent to segment EG, then chord AB is congruent to CD" I thought that EF has to be perpendicular to AB and EG has to be perpendicular to CD to say that the chords AB and CD are congruent, or am I wrong?

I'm a bit confused, as both videos have many likes, so I think I might be wrong. Thanks in advance for correcting me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The 4 conclusion is wrong - a radii can bisect a chord and not being perpendicular

Comment: Thanks, what about the second video? At 3:40 he says "because EF is congruent to EG; then AB is congruent to CD", which is wrong in my opinion as EF has to be perpendicular to AB and EG has to be perpendicular to CD in order to say that AB is congruent to CD. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: EF and EG are congruent and perpendicular as defined by distance. Than you prove that AB is congruent (=) to CD based on SAS (one of the sides is the radii of the circle. It is not clear what the guy tries to prove with the drawings.

Comment: I basically mean the sentence that starts at 3:30 is incorrect "You need to know that if 2 chords of a circle are equidistant from the centre, then they are congruent".

Comment: This statement is true and can be proven.

Comment: @Moti I mean if two line segments between a centre of a circle and two chords are congruent doesn't mean that the chords are congruent (and that's what he said in the video - because EF =EG, then AB = CD), otherwise a case like this may occure:[link](https://i.ibb.co/m4Bn947/measurement.png)

Comment: Their distance NEED to be congruent. Distance means perpendicular. Your drawing is not showing distance.